# Кликабельные даты в datepicker

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой вот календарь

[image: Imgur]

Как сделать так, чтобы даты в нем были кликабельные и были ссылками?
Код - http://gruzimfile.ru/file/268

В 2045 строке прописал ссылку, но она не работает, а также месяц определяется не правильно. Например, сегодня февраль, но там отображается первый месяц.

```
 href='/news/search.php?data=" + printDate.getFullYear() + "-" + printDate.getMonth() + "-" + printDate.getDate() + "'
```

Comment: В прикрепленном архиве только jquery-ui. Что касается кликабельности дат, то они ведь у Datepicker'а по умолчанию кликабельны
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

Comment: Кликабельны, но нужно чтобы даты были ссылками. И в том файле я пытался прописать ссылку. И календарь у меня статичный http://gos.xlandcms.ru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Править стороннюю библиотеку - не очень хорошая идея, т.к. дальнейшее обновление будет затруднено.

Если стоит задача по клику на дне просто выполнять переход на страницу с параметрами выбранной даты, то решается она очень просто:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            location.href = "/news?date=" + selectedDate; // /news?date=2014-02-22
        }
    });
});
```

Если же вам нужны именно ссылки на датах, то тут все посложнее. Идея такая.

Datepicker позволяет задавать ячейкам свои классы (через beforeShowDay). Прописываем каждой ячейке ее дату в виде yyyy-mm-dd, а при наведении мыши (к сожалению, не увидел в API методов, позволяющих это сделать по окончании перерисовки календаря) у ссылки в этой ячейке поменять href на тот, что мы в классе прописали.

```
$(function() {
    function markDays(date) {
        return [true, 'with-date ' + $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date)];
    }

    var $datepicker = $("#datepicker");

    $datepicker.on('mouseover', '.with-date', function () {
        var d = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+-\d+-\d+/)[0];
        $(this).find('a').attr('href', "/news?date=" + d);
    });

    $datepicker.datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: markDays,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            console.log("/news?date=" + selectedDate); // /news?date=2014-02-22
        }
    });
});
```

Если эту мысль развить, думаю, можно и более красивую реализацию сделать, но приведенный код [задачу выполняет](http://jsfiddle.net/NbTNH/1/).

Comment: Спасибо. Первого кода достаточно.